# How to figure out the reason why query returns no result?

Tags: mongodb

Is there is a way to find out the reason why a query would return no result in monogodb ?

Suppose we have a collections that stores employees and I want to fetch any employee with the name X, address Y and age Z.

I will write some query like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 

query.put("name","X"); query.put("address","Y"); query.put("age","z");
```

If this query returns null, how do I know whether it is because no employee with the name X, or no employee with the address Y, or no employee with the age z ?  or there is way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it out of the box. You have to perform multiple queries or make one query with first condition and iterate over collection in your application code to find out whether others conditions match

Comment: exactly. Try if you can find the same document via the `mongo` shell

Comment: Ok fine, but, what happens if the amount of the data to be load is very large that it can not be handled in memory ?

Comment: You can use server side execution, write your own search using javascript and call mongodb function from your application code. Your function can return condition which does not match or object which was found. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return any documents because no documents matched your criteria. If you really want to know which one, then make 3 separate queries and filter/merge results on the client.